# Create SSRS Subscription to XLTX (Excel Template)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to get the subscription for SSRS to send the CSV data to an existing Excel template so that the data is formatted to our excel reports and all the conditional formatting in them every morning but it's just creating a new file.  How do I send the data to a specific template file?

Answer (score 0):

While SSRS doesn't have built-in functionality for exporting directly to an Excel template, I have a suggestion for a workaround. Use SSRS to export the data in CSV or Excel format. Then, in the Excel template file, go to the Data menu and select Get Data > From File. This lets you use Excel's built-in Power Query functionality to reference the exported file as a data source.

One of the benefits of this approach is that to get fresh data all you need to do is overwrite the data file and then click "Refresh All" in your Excel file. You can also take advantage of the transformation functions that are available in Power Query to avoid repetitive cleanup tasks if needed.

Comment: Nice idea's ty for the suggestion, I like it!  Now is there a way to automate this refresh at say 1am on a server somewhere?  Right now we have an Access DB that kicks off reports from a Task Manager job and the Access DB's call each other to create all the reports and I really need to get away from this as someone needs to be logged into the computer and it reboots often because of windows updates which messes everything up.

Comment: @JustAnotherFaceInTheCode One option is to use an SSRS subscription to create the file in a Windows share. Another option would be to use an SSIS job and not use SSRS at all.